# Можно ли запустить docker контейнер "открыто"?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, unix

Хочу запустить у себя на компе docker контейнер, чтобы на него можно было подключиться с другого компьютера?

Вроде как можно .
Контейнер ubuntu(просто скачал с dockerhub).
Как пытаюсь запустить контейнер - `docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5656:5656 -i -t ubuntu`.
Возможно некая боль - я запускаю это дело в Power Shell(Windows).

Comment: --network=host попробуйте

Comment: @gbg, спасибо вроде как заработало.
Комманда - docker run -p 192.168.202.65:22:22 --network=host -i -t ubuntu
Но теперь ругается что не дает доступа)) 

PS X:\> ssh 192.168.202.65 -p 3131
ssh: connect to host 192.168.202.65 port 3131: Connection refused

Это уже с контейнером проблемы?

Comment: Вы сервер ssh в контейнере перенастроили на порт 3131?

Comment: @gbg, честно не знаю.
Я скачал ubuntu контейнер, (через команду docker pull ubuntu )
И пывтаюсь запустить этот контейнер с командой выше.

Comment: docker ps - список работающих контейнеров

docker exec -it [контейнер] /bin/bash - получить командную строку

Comment: @gbg, спасибо за команду)) Но я хочу развернуть контейнер как удаленную машину - наверное правильно так сказать, чтобы по ssh(вроде только так и можно) к ней подключиться и на ней работать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95707/discussion-between-gbg-and-sank).

Comment: @gbg, спасибо за помощь.
Добавите свой ответ как правильный?

Я запускаю так : docker run -p 3131:22 -i -t <имя image> /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас нарушен синтаксис параметра `-p`

Правильно указывать в этом параметре `[порт хоста]:[порт контейнера]`

**Пример:**

`docker run -p 3131:22 -i -t <имя image> /bin/bash`

**Краткая памятка по командам:**

`docker ps` - список работающих контейнеров

`docker exec -it [контейнер] /bin/bash` - получить командную строку этого контейнера

Comment: синтаксис параметра `-p` не нарушен, IP для привязки порта указывать можно и даже нужно